# Comparing 2 pdf files to check for their similarity using BERT

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, bert-language-model

I have 2 PDF files which I want to compare with each other and get similarity score, from what I have been able to research online and find is a sentence or a paragraph being compared to each other, but I want to compare the between the pdfs as a whole and not a paragraph. I want to do this using BERT.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: @KJ If I would be extracting text from the pdfs to compare them , wont the text then be too big to be compared with each other ? For when lets say the PDFs are big like over 50pgs

Comment: Thanks for you input , if you can share some links or code to refer to than that you be great. Thanks